# Add 110 outlet to 220 electrical box

Tags: electrical

I have this box on the side of my house that powers my hottub.
[image: Hot Tub Electrical Box]

Is it possible (without violating typical code) to add a 15 amp 110 breaker in this box with intention of powering a small (1/3 HP) sump pump.

The sump pump is not critical to keeping my home dry.  I am just drying up a spot in my yard that is always a bit wet.

[EDIT] It is a 60amp breaker in the main panel feeding this box and there is a 60amp breaker in this box.  It services a hot tub.

Comment: What is the size breaker in this box?

Comment: Also, verify that there is actually a neutral in this box. If it's just a 240V load, they may have just run two hots and ground. It's not legal to use the ground as a neutral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are 2 positions available to add new breakers. The panel will need to be opened to know for sure, also make sure to get the correct brand and type for that panel. I would make the first outlet a GFCI since it is outside and you would be good to go. The answer is yes it is possible within code.

Comment: If that is indeed a mini-subpanel, you just nailed the answer.  You just have to watch out, I've seen where those micro-panels have knockouts where they do not actually have slots.